# "That's an opinion"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In this clip *(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRZ4zci_YUU)*, **Jimmy Fallon** has said:

> Halsey, we all know that you are an amazing singer

and **Halsey** responsed:

> That's an opinion

What does she mean?

Comment: Fallon says "we all know." That is, it's a fact that Halsey is an amazing singer. Halsey replies that this is (just) an opinion, a subjective judgment. She's deflecting a compliment that only the arrogant would accept at face value.